# Unable to download TestNG

Tags: maven, testng

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

> Software being installed: TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional)
>   6.13.0.201712040650 (org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group 6.13.0.201712040650)   Missing requirement: TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration 6.13.0.201712040650 (org.testng.eclipse.maven
>   6.13.0.201712040650) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional) 6.13.0.201712040650 (org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group 6.13.0.201712040650)
>       To: org.testng.eclipse.maven [6.13.0.201712040650]

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that there's missing M2E plugin in your Eclipse, so could you try not install the optional TestNG M2E Integration plugin? or, you need to have M2E 1.5 or above installed first.